# Get highest maximum value (average) of 4 unique documents mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a collection of documents that look like this:

```js
{
     cards: ['card1', 'card257', 'card35', 'card443', 'card67'],
     rating: 74
}
```

All documents in the DB have a unique set of `cards`, but many documents can share elements between their `cards` arrays. What I hope to do is find the combination of any 4 documents that have the highest maximum rating together, i.e. the highest average. However, none of the 4 documents can share any of the same elements from their `cards` array.

Is this possible to do using aggregation? I have been able to do it without a query, and doing it all with Nodejs, but computing time is starting to get out of hand with the amount of data I have stored. Thanks!

Comment: highest maximum and highest average aren't actually the same thing, so you probably want to formally describe what you need (i.e. explicitly describe the document properties you're looking for, and how to weigh them), and then tailor the question to that =)
Also, when it comes to "is it possible?" questions: of course it's possible. Everything can be programmed, it might just need an entirely new technology to be developed to act as intermediary. So that's not your question: take a moment to figure out the _real_ question, and then ask that instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how do they differ? the combination of 4 elements with the highest value together would mean that that combination also has the highest average, no?

Comment: Sure but then notice what you just said: if you want the highest valued documents, their average is _entirely_ irrelevant: you just want the highest valued documents,  which is just "order by value, select the first N rows", done. So if that's _not_ what you need, you'll want to explain _why_ that's not what you need, and show code (with "demo" data and desired output) that illustrates what you need instead of the standard "order/group, and limit".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Correct, the 4 highest valued documents that are completely unique as described above.

Comment: Right, so: why does "ordering by value, limiting to 4, and then being done" not work for you in this case?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Documents can share the same elements in their `cards` property. I thought that was implied, maybe I should have made that more clear. My apologies.

Comment: That's why I recommended being explicit in your post: anything you think is implied, make explicit. Give [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) a read through, and apply that your post. It's usually worth the effort.

Comment: i think its best to solve it in memory in an efficient way first and then look how to do it in mongodb.

Comment: @Takis_ I have spent days working on it, but ultimately the problem cannot be much faster than O(n^4). And n > 500000. I need to figure out how to implement some aggregation so that the system doesn't return `Out of memory` errors

Comment: It is generally efficient to perform the query on the database server and retrieve the results - rather than read the documents into the application and perform the logic. You may have advantage of using indexes on the database server, if applicable. For a large dataset you will eventually run into memory issues on the database server or the application - you need to use appropriate tools and for that and figure what is more efficient. Aggregation has an option `allowDiskUse` to overcome memory constraints.